# Waiting, assembly emu8086

Tags: assembly, wait, emu8086

I am trying to wait about 0.02 seconds in assembly, emu8086.
That is my code so far:

```
mov ah, 00h
int 1ah ; Interrupt "get system time"
mov si, dx
mov bx, 1h ; How many ticks to wait (9/18=0.5 second)
tick:
mov ah, 00h
int 1ah
cmp si, dx ; Checks how many ticks has passed
jz tick 
mov si, dx
dec bx
jnz tick
ret
endp
```

bx is the time it should wait (1 tick equals 1/18 seconds). Apparently, I am not able to put less than 1 tick, and for 0.02 seconds i need 0.36 ticks. 
Thank you very much!

Comment: thanks, havent seen it, ill check it out

Comment: How do I rate you 5 stars?

Comment: [so] is a bit special in comparison with other "discussion forums" -- in fact it's not a discussion forum, it's a Q&A site. Duplicate questions should be closed as duplicates. I don't have the privileges to close vote, someone else would do that. | Note that you should do serious research before asking.

Comment: For good questions that receives answers, you can [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). | Also, [you don't need to have a "Thank you very much"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950), similar to how we don't do that on Wikipedia.

Comment: @Q29vbA you can also upvote the question/answers which you find useful and informative.